# Deleting friends in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My goal is to be able to remove friends in a user's profile. Here is what I have so far:

Code in my friendships_controller.rb:

```
def destroy  
    @user.friends.destroy
  end
```

Route:

```
get "/friendships" => 'friendships#destroy', as: 'destroy_friendship'
```

User.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
   def friends
    friendships = Friendship.where(user_id: self.id) #here the self refers to the native user id. USER OBJECT
    friend_list = Array.new
    friendships.each do |friendship|
      friend_list << User.find_by_id(friendship.friendship_id)
    end
    return friend_list.uniq
end
```

Friendship.rb model:

```
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
```

User show page:

```
<b>Friends</b>
<% @user.friends.each do |friend| %><br /> 
    <%= friend.name %>
    <%= link_to "Remove", friend, method: :delete %>
    <%end%>
```

I am very confused at how to solve this problem. Especially because of the error `undefined method`friends' for nil:NilClass`. Even though it is a helper_method so shouldn't it be available everywhere?

Comment: Try with `@user.friendships.destroy_all` for deleting all friend

Comment: Srry I didn't make it clear but I just want to delete one friend.

Comment: Can you post the full controller code? Seems like you don't have `@user` defined.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `@user` object is `nil`. You don't need to write `friends` method in your `Friendhips` model. When you write

> has_many :friends

in your User model, Rails provides you this friends method which will return all the friends of a single user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<% @user.friends.each do |friend| %><br /> 
  <%= friend.name %>
  <%= link_to "Remove", friend, method: :delete %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: I get an error saying 
undefined method `user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f3851b9a678>:0x007f3851b99c28>

Comment: I dont mean to be rude but this school project is due tommorow it would be so kind of you to reply as quickly as possible.

Comment: Please join here [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85381/rails-has-many-through)

Answer (score 0):

several issues here.

1) if you want to destroy a friendship, but not remove the friend's account from the database, you need to destroy the user's friendship, not user's 'friend'

so for your show file in user, you can do this (though it's a bit unconventional):

```
<b>Friends</b>
<% @user.friendships.each do |friendship| %><br /> 
    <%= friendship.friend.name %> 
    <%= link_to "Remove", friendship, method: :delete %>
<%end%>
```

in your friendship controller you then can use the default destroy action, where what's deleted is the @friendship

friendships_controller.rb

```
def destroy 
   @friendship.destroy
end
```